# Remove background (not just hide) from jqplot

Tags: javascript, jqplot

[image]

As you can see from my example above, there is a lot of padding around the actual pie chart. I know how to make the white background transparent, but that still does not remove the actual canvas background. I need the precious space it is wasting and need my pie charts (the circles) a lot closer together.

Technically I am using primefaces and JSF but I am overriding their pieChart which is just a jqplot. Here is my javascript extender code to make the background transparent

```
this.cfg.seriesDefault.shadow = false;
this.cfg.grid = {
   shadow: false,
   drawBorder: false,
   background: "transparent"
};
```

Also css code incase that is where I need to edit

(redundant)

```
.jqplot-event-canvas {
   background: transparent
}
```

I've tried adding background-size to the css but no luck. The only way I can get the size to change is via the XHTML code

```
<p:chart type="pie" model="#{charts}" style="width:125px,height:100px" />
```

But that changes the entire rectangle.

Thanks for any help.

*edit My code shows `background: "transparent"` but the image is actually with that line commented out, so it can be seen.